# Do questions about haftarot belong in the tag for the corresponding parsha?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should a question about a particular haftarah be given the tag for the parasha that it goes along with? If so, what should be done about haftarot that are *usually* read with one parasha, but sometimes read with a different parasha? For example, the haftarah that is *typically* called the haftarah for Parashat Pinchas is very rarely read and instead the haftarah for Matot is read with Pinchas while the following week will be Matot-Masei and the haftarah for Masei is read.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that a tag isn't misleading, whether to include it on a question is a matter of priority, taking into account other tags that could apply and the limit of five tags total on a question.

Given that, I think that the following qualities should have more or less influence on prioritizing including a *parsha* tag on questions related to *Navi* text that's in that *parsha*'s *haftara*:

- If the question is about the connection of the text to that *parsha*, then the *parsha* tag [should](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3634/2) almost definitely be there, since the *parsha* itself is directly relevant to the question.
- If the question refers to the text in the context of its being a *haftara*, then whatever *parsha* is referenced could be included as a tag, depending on what other tags are indicated. The fact that the question refers to the text in terms of its being a *haftara* is a good clue that other people might be interested in that text due to that context. Secondarily, any other *parshiyot* or holidays on which the same text is a *haftara* could be included, too, since the same clue applies, dilutedly, to the context of being in *haftarot* in general.
- If the question makes no reference to the fact that the text is part of a *haftara*, but you think that some people might be interested in this text in the context of its being a *haftara*, then I'd suggest editing the question to include a nod to that context, and then, depending on other indicated tags, adding tags for [whatever](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3633/2) *parshiyot*'s or holidays' *haftarot* the text appears in. Adding such tags without also editing the question could be confusing to people who don't realize that the text is part of a *haftara*.

Comment: So this http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45828/759 should be tagged Devarim? And this http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33240/759 Sukkot? And this http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13488/759 Fast-days? And this http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34228/759 Yitro? And this http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27698/759 Behaalotcha? And this http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23386/759 Bamidbar?

Comment: @DoubleAA By the framework I'm suggesting, these would fall into the third bullet. Is the possible association with the as-yet-unmentioned *parsha* or holiday strong enough that it's worth editing into the question ~"As seen in *haftarat Devarim*"?

Answer (score 1):

I think questions about Haftarot should only be tagged with a Parsha if they ask about the connection of the Parsha to the reading. If it is just a local issue in the Navi, then its being a Haftara in some years/communities isn't relevant.

The Parsha-tag chosen should reflect the connection being asked about, whether or not it is the official "title" of the Haftara.

Answer (score -1):

I think the question should be tagged with the name of the listed Parsha, even if it often is moved. The goal of tagging is to aid searching, so we should put a parsha-tag on, and this is the only system that doesn't involve guessing which is more common (is it more common for Haazinu to be Shuva or Shirat David?).

Comment: This might mean we have to double tag Haftarot for KiTeitzei-Noach, Reeh-Noach, Behaalotcha-Chanukkah, Vayakhel-Chanukkah, Haazinu-Pesach, Vayelech-Vayetzei, and Pesach-YomHaatzmaut.

Comment: Are you saying that any question that hits a verse that happens to be part of a *haftara* or *haftarot* should be tagged with the associated parsh[a][iyot]?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Yes. For better or worse, many people may be more familiar with it as a piece of Haftara X than a piece of Book X. Hence an aid in searching. Ex. is עגלה יפיפיה from Yeshaya or Yirmiya? Well I know it's from Bo's Haftara...